# Can I do Android/g1 tethering without root?

Tags: tethering, htc-dream

Can I do Android/g1 tethering without root?

Comment: Just root it - it has gotten even easier [now](https://web.archive.org/web/20100606022207/http://androidandme.com/2009/08/news/how-to-root-a-t-mobile-g1-and-mytouch-3g-android-phone) - takes 5 minutes, giving you tethering and so much more.

Comment: I do it with Proxoid.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, according to [AllShadow - Tether Your Android (G1) Without Root](https://web.archive.org/web/20101022064405/http://www.allshadow.com/2009/03/30/tether-your-android-g1-without-root/):

> This one is for the majority of Android owners who don’t want to be bothered with rooting on the G1 (Android). Mucho gracias to [Tremendo Slap](https://web.archive.org/web/20101022064405/http://allshadow.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5324#p38064) for digging this one up. June Fabric has released an app for Windows that also installs another app on Android that allows you to tether to 3G. Most users say it works flawlessly even with VPN connections. A few connections were dropped here and there but overall a success. This is an app that I know many of you have been waiting for.
>
> For those wondering, tethering is connecting your device to your laptop and using your device's internet connection on your laptop.
>
> So download [PdaNet beta 1.12](https://web.archive.org/web/20101022064405/http://www.junefabrics.com/bin/PdaNetA112.exe) ([or Vista 64](https://web.archive.org/web/20101022064405/http://www.junefabrics.com/bin/PdaNetA112x64.exe))
>
> [PdaNet](https://pdanet.co/)
>
> Note This is probably in violation of your carrier’s TOS. For T-Mobile the 1GB per month data cap was lifted awhile ago but there is word that users that pass the 1GB limit will be limited to 50Kbps for data past that mark. **I would advise using this only if you are in dire need. I would advise against canceling your home internet plan as well**

Comment: I have a T-Mobile MDA (HTC Wizard) and it came with tethering software (which I have used) so I think T-Mobile is OK with tethering.

Comment: There can also be a difference between countries ;-)

Comment: I've used PdaNet and my opinion is that, while it can work, it is definitely not something to replace any real connection.  It's "flaky" enough that the reliability should be considered only for absolute necessity.

Answer (score 4):

With rooting being so easy, why not?  [Haykuro's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20090818080138/http://haykuro.theiphoneproject.org:80/?page_id=35) is very easy to follow and has been recommended on other threads on this site. Once you're rooted just go to https://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/ and look for the .apk download on the right-side.

Comment: does market and other standard things still work when rooted?

Comment: It depends on the ROMs, but with the ROM linked below on my rooted G1, I can access free apps, I have never tried a paid app.  I also have Exchange ActiveSync and Tethering.  Honestly, there is nothing I can think of that does not work.  It is an improvement over the stock ROMs.  

Link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=539744

As of writing this, the latest version of my preferred ROM is update-cm-3.9.5-signed.zip, which is found on the above page.

Good luck if you do it.  Don't hesitate to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: @StewartRobinson I rooted my G1 with Universal Androot. If you use your new root privileges to mod your phone or install a new OS, it will work differently -- that depends on the OS. But just rooting it won't disable the Android Market or any of the apps you're already running.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Azilink](https://github.com/hanetzer/azilink/blob/master/HOWTO). It does not require root access. Works just as advertised.

Just don't forget to circumvent the lame HTTP user agent blocks that your ISPs might have put in place.